Выполняю INSERT через php в поле пароля вместо указанного мною значения вставляется значение 'root'
Вот сам код.
Все данные кроме пароля ставятся как надо. Если я пишу логин Matvey то в БД и отображается Matvey, но пишу пароль 12345 в бд он отображается как root. Использую mamp phpmyadmin
$login = $_POST['login'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

if($password == $confirmPassword){
    require_once 'connect.php';
     $check_login = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE login = '$login'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_login) > 0){
        header('Location: ../registration.php');
    }
    else{
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users2 (login, email, pass) VALUES ('$login', '$email', '$password') ");
        header('Location: ../login.php');
    }
}
else{
    // условие что пароли не совпадают суда дописать код
}


пишу пароль 12345 в бд он отображается как root А в $_POST['password'] что попадает?

Ну наверное в файле connect.php переменная $password уже установлена, потому в запрос подставляется $password из connect.php, который и есть паролем для доступа к Вашей БД.

Спасибо огромное за помощь действительно всё дело было в require_once 'connect.php'; из за того что там уже прописан $password сам бы я наверное даже не догадался посмотреть на эту строчку

Вы уже разобрались, но вообще почитайте про безопасность паролей. Хранить пароли в БД в открытом виде — это очень, очень плохо с точки зрения безопасности!
